# How to use rd command in windows registry?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have a string value set in CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce whose goal is to delete a folder on reboot. Its value is :

```
rd /s /q "ThisPath"
```

It does not delete anything that way.
If I instead use :

```
cmd.exe /c rd /s /q "ThisPath"
```

It works after displaying a black box for a fraction of seconds. Is there a way to send the first command without displaying the black box ?

Answer (score 0):

The `rd` command you are trying to execute from `CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce` is not an executable but an internal command to `cmd.exe` so it fails if you try to run it on its own.

The `rd` command will only work inside a `cmd.exe` instance.

The "black box" you see flashing at startup is `cmd.exe` starting up, executing the `rd` command and closing again.

If you put the `rd` command in a batch file, you could start it minimized with:

`cmd.exe /c start /min c:\path\to\RemoveDir.bat`

This will make it less visible.